# How can the same button send a form and redirect to Stripe checkout?

Tags: flask, stripe-payments

So I am building a website for a hotel and I'm currently working on implementing an online payment system, for which I'm using Stripe. The process goes as:

1. The client introduces the check-in date, check-out date and the type of room:

   ```py
   @app.route('/booking', methods=['GET', 'POST']
   def booking():
      form = BookForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
          # there are is an if-elif here, that checks if the check-in day
          # and check-out day are the same or if the check-in date is bigger
          # than the check-out date
          else:
              roomid = search_room(int(form.room_type.data))
              # this function returns the ID of the room available from the
              # database
              if roomid not Null:
                  # here I insert into session the room ID, check-in day, month
                  # year, check-out day, month, year
                  return redirect(url_for('booking2'))
      return render_template('booking.html', form=form)
   ```

   There are no issues here, everything works as expected.

   The code for `BookForm` is:

   ```py
   class BookForm(FlaskForm):
      From = DateField('From*', format='%d/%m/%Y', validators=[DataRequired()])
      To = DateField('To*', format='%d/%m/%Y', validators=[DataRequired()])
      room = SelectField('Camera type*', validators=[DataRequired()], default='Room1', choices=[('1', 'Room1'), ('2', 'Room2')])
      submit = SubmitField('Check')
   ```
2. The client gets redirected to `booking2`, where they have to fill in personal
   data:

   ```py
   @app.route('/booking2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def booking2():
      form = ClientForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
         # same thing as in the booking route, I check the form data for stuff
         # such as if the e-mails correspond, if the phone number .isdigit(), etc.
         # if all the data is ok:
         else:
            # again, as in the booking route, insert into session all the data form:
            # first_name, last_name, email, phonenr, etc.
            return redirect(url_for('booking3'))
      # here, I check if all the data from the booking route (checkin_day, checkin_month, etc.) is in the session:
      if 'checkin_day' in session and 'checkin_month' in session and ... :
         return render_template('booking2.html', form = form, iday = session['checkin_day'], ...)
      # if all this data isn't in the session, that means that the client went directly to the booking2 route, so I redirect them back to booking
      else:
          return redirect(url_for('booking'))
   ```

   The code for `ClientForm` is:

   ```py
   class ClientForm(FlaskForm):
       last_name = StringField('Last name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
       first_name = StringField('First name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
       # etc.
       # The form is working properly
   ```

   The HTML for `booking2.html` is:

   ```html
   <html>
   <head>
       <!-- Nothing interesting in the head, just css includes, etc. -->
   </head>
   <body>
       <!-- Again, nothing interesting here -->
       <h2>
          ROOM: #{{ room_id }}<br>
          CHECK-IN: {{ iday }}/{{ imonth }}/{{ iyear }}<br>
          CHECK-OUT: {{ oday }}/{{ omonth }}/{{ oyear }}<br>
          NUMBER OF NIGHTS: {{ nights }}<br>
          TOTAL COST: {{ total_price }} RON<br>
       </h2>
       <!-- Next comes the form itself -->
       <form action="" method="post">
           {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
           <div class="controls">
               {{ form.last_name.label }}<br>
               {{ form.last_name(size=10, class="floatLabel") }}
           </div>
           <!-- and so on for the other fields -->
           <div>
               {{ form.submit(id="buy_now_btn", class="contbtn col-1-4") }}
           </div>
       </form>
   ```

And, finally, here is my issue: In JS, I query the submit button by ID, and I add an event listener.

```
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
fetch('/stripe_pay')
.then((result) => { return result.json(); })
.then((data) => {
    var stripe = Stripe(data.checkout_public_key);
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: data.checkout_session_id
    }).then(function (result) { 
    });
})
```

});

In the `stripe_pay` route I create the `stripe.checkout.Session` and return the `checkout.Session` ID and my public API key.

The `booking3` route to which I redirect to in the `booking2` route if all the data is ok and entered in the session, is just a page which thanks the client for the payment and assures the payment was successful. The `booking3` is the `success_url` of the `stripe.checkout.Session` created in the `stripe_pay` route.

The problem is, whenever I press the submit button on the `booking2` route, I get redirected straight to `booking3`, without getting redirected to Stripe's checkout page and completing the payment, therefore the payment appears as incompleted in Stripe's dashboard.

Comment: Post your html code for the form as well as the flask route that handles the form submission to our original post.

Comment: But other than that, how I would go about maybe solving this is. 1. When user hits the submit button it get would get routed to a function/route def handle_form_data() , which after processing the form data would ```return redirect(url_for("stripe_checkout_page"))```

Comment: HTML-wise there is nothing interesting, this is the HTML for the submit button `{{ form.submit(id="buy_now_btn", class="contbutton col-1-4") }}`. The route that handles the form just checks for stuff such as if the e-mails correspond or if the phone number is digits only. If all these things succeed, I insert into the `session` all the personal data. If the form validates and the data is inserted, I don't return anything (`render_template` or `redirect`), because from this point on I'm thinking that the JS will come into play.

Comment: " because from this point on I'm thinking that the JS will come into play" . How? Why? and Where will JS come into play? Also are you successfully inserting the data into session on submit  @DumiB  ?

Comment: The data is going the way it should in `session`, I've tested it. By "JS will come into play" I mean that from that part forward I'm dealing with things in JavaScript, Flask has nothing left to do until the payment was successful

Comment: You asked 'How can the same button send a form and redirect to Stripe checkout?' , I have mentioned a step you could possibly take to do it above, I can't think of another way it would be possible to do it with the given information currently. If that does not meet your requirements you might want to provide an [MRE]  :D

Comment: I think I have properly formatted and updated everything. Hopefully my question is unambiguous now :D